# Anjularjs call a controller method every time select changes

Tags: angularjs

Basic question about angularjs. I have two models: reservations and tables. I show a list of reservations and then when the user selects the table for a reservation, I want to update the tables model to contain a reservation.

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations">
<td><select ng-model="selectedTable" ng-options="table.name for table in tables">
</td>
```

Essentially what I need is that whenever a table is selected, I need access to both the reservation and the table in a method on the controller.

Is a directive that links to a controller method the right way to do this? I'm not sure how to pass the variables in.

Thanks

edit:

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations">
<td><select ng-model="reservation.selectedTable" ng-options="table.name for table in   tables">
 </td>
```

I tried doing it this way. But since table is an object and not a property, the child scope still creates the property instead of a reference to the parent property. I also tried adding "as table.name" but it didn't work.

```
<tr ng-repeat="reservation in reservations">
<td><select ng-model="reservation.selectedTable" ng-options="table.name as table.name for table in   tables">
 </td>
```

Comment: Nevermind it looks like it worked but anjularjs chome extension doesn't always update the model properly

Answer (score 2):

Looking at you html, what i can suggest you would be to use `ng-change` on the `select` dropdown.

```
<select ng-model="selectedTable" ng-options="table.name for table in tables" ng-change="tableSelected(reservation,selectedTable)">
```

On the controller you can have method like

```
$scope.tableSelected=function((reservation,selectedTable) {

}
```

Remember `ng-repeat` creates new scope. Also The `selectedTable` would be get set for each ng-repeat scope.

Comment: How would I do it so that the child scopes for each ng-repeat are referencing the parent scopes?

Comment: Child scope has access to parent scope elements. Please go through this wiki that explains about scope inheritance https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes